# DeflateStream CopyTo writes nothing and throws no exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, compression, zip

I've basically copied this code sample directly from msdn with some minimal changes. The `CopyTo` method is silently failing and I have no idea why. What would cause this behavior? It is being passed a 78 KB zipped folder with a single text file inside of it. The returned `FileInfo` object points to a 0 KB file. No exceptions are thrown.

```
    public static FileInfo DecompressFile(FileInfo fi)
    {
        // Get the stream of the source file.
        using (FileStream inFile = fi.OpenRead())
        {
            // Get original file extension, 
            // for example "doc" from report.doc.cmp.
            string curFile = fi.FullName;
            string origName = curFile.Remove(curFile.Length
                    - fi.Extension.Length);

            //Create the decompressed file.
            using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(origName))
            {
                // work around for incompatible compression formats found
                // here http://george.chiramattel.com/blog/2007/09/deflatestream-block-length-does-not-match.html
                inFile.ReadByte();
                inFile.ReadByte();

                using (DeflateStream Decompress = new DeflateStream(inFile,
                    CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    // Copy the decompression stream 
                    // into the output file.
                    Decompress.CopyTo(outFile);

                    return new FileInfo(origName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What type of file are you trying to read and decompress?  A .gz, a .zip, or something else?

Comment: @huntharo it's a .zip.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment you say that you are trying to decompress a zip file. The `DeflateStream` class can not be used like this on a zip file. The [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/4yy62ycx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you mentioned uses `DeflateStream` to create individual compressed files and then uncompresses them.

Although zip files might use the same algorithm (not sure about that) they are not just compressed versions of a single file. A zip file is a container that can hold many files and/or folders.

If you can use .NET Framework 4.5 I would suggest to use the new [`ZipFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx) or [`ZipArchive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx) class. If you must use an earlier framework version there are free libraries you can use (like [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) or [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/)).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on .NET 4. I was originally trying to use the `Zipfile` class but realized it wasn't an option. I may have to go with one of those third party libraries but would prefer not to.